# PrimeFaces commandButton not working after being loaded from AJAX

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm working on a project with JSF + Primefaces 6.0. 
On this particular page there is something wrong which I don't know how to fix.
When #selected-operator or #selected-site values are changed the form#operatorsForm is updated correctly via AJAX and the results are displayed in the datatable.

The problem is when I click on the commandButton that is loaded within the datatable the modal dialog "confirmWV" is not showing. 
On my other pages I have the same code for modals but buttons there are not loaded via AJAX so this makes me think it is AJAX related issue.
When debugging, clicking on the button is not calling the method confirmOperatorsRightsAction().

Thank you for your help!

page.xhtml

```
<h:form id="operatorForm">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="selected-operator"
        value="#{operatorController.selectedOperator}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Choose operator" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{operatorBean.getOperatorsList()}"
            var="operator" itemLabel="#{operator.username}"
            itemValue="#{operator.idPk}" />
        <f:ajax execute="selected-operator" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:selectOneMenu id="selected-site"
            value="#{operatorBean.selectedSite}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Choose site" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{operatorBean.getSites()}"
            var="site" itemLabel="#{site.strname}" itemValue="#{site.idPk}" />
        <f:ajax execute="selected-site" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

</h:form>


<h:form id="operatorsForm">
    <p:dataTable var="operatorSite"
        value="#{operatorBean.getOperatorSites()}"
        id="operators-list">

        <p:column headerText="#{msg['item.Username']}">
            #{operatorSite.operator.username}
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{msg['item_SiteName']}">
            #{operatorSite.site.strname}
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="">
            <p:commandButton
                actionListener="#{operatorBean.confirmOperatorsRightsAction(operatorSite)}"
                                value="#{msg['item_Delete']}"
                                icon="fa fa-trash">
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<p:dialog widgetVar="confirmWV" modal="true"
    header="#{msg['modal.confirm.title']}" height="150" width="450">
    <h:form id="confirmOperatorForm">
        <my:confirm />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

OperatorBean.java

```
public void confirmOperatorsRightsAction(OperatorSite os) {

    //some code here
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("confirmOperatorForm");

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('confirmWV').show();");

}
```

Comment: Why you required three different form in single page?

Comment: I think this way forms are easier to control. What do you suggest?

Comment: If you will do with this way you can not update one form from another form action or button .

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure? Now changing values in #operatorForm is updating #operatorsForm without any issues. 
Having a single form for the page caused much more issues with validation of inputs.

Comment: Single form thing will work properly but clicking on one form and trying to update another form value is not straight forward